# pyqt Treewidget header click is not working

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt4

pyqt Treewidget header is not emitting signal.

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore


class mainwin(QtGui.QWidget):
     def __init__(self, parent = None):
          QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
          self.list = QtGui.QTreeWidget()
          self.list.setHeaderLabels(["Raton", "name", "address"])


          self.head = QtGui.QHeaderView(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal)
          self.head.setClickable(True)

          self.list.setHeader(self.head)
          self.head.sectionClicked.connect(self.test)

    def test(self):
         print("ok")
```

when i clicked on header nothing happens. but.

```
          self.list.header().setClickable(True)
          self.list.header().sectionClicked.connect(self.test)
```

its working. Why ? whats wrong in my above code?(QtGui.QHeaderView())

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`setClickable` should called after `setHeader`.

```
     self.list.setHeader(self.head)
     self.head.setClickable(True)
```

`self.list.setHeader(..)` make `self.head` unclickable.

**UPDATE**

`setClickable` is obsolete. Use `setSectionsClickable` instead.

Comment: Should this not be now ` setSectionsClickable` with the latest qt?

Comment: @user1767754, Thank you for the comment. I updated the answer accordingly.